# global web.config overrides site web.config?

Tags: asp.net

In trying to speed up my ASP.Net development build times, I changed my "global" web.config file (`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config`) as follows

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <compilation batch="false">
```

That really sped up the first page access of my site after doing a build.

What surprises me is that our **site's** `web.config` has

```
    <compilation batch="true">
```

but the global setting is the one that seems to be in effect. I would expect that the site web.config would override the global web.config.  Is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Global `web.config` doesn't override site `web.config`.

try this: set in global `web.config`

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="TruncLongText-Size" value="150"/>
```

and in local `web.config`

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="TruncLongText-Size" value="150"/>
```

then prompt the result in a page.

What do you see?

Comment: Maybe that applies to `appSettings` but not to `compilation`?